# EXTRACT YEAR from column and update another column PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have created another column in my table, for year which I would like to populated it from same table column tdate by extracting the year, can someone please advise how I can do that?

SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR from tdate) from test_tb, BUT how I can assigned the value now for each row?

```
tdate                        year
2006-01-02 00:00:01.132000   null
2007-01-02 00:00:01.234000   null  
2008-01-02 00:00:01.336000   null
2009-01-02 00:00:01.538000   null
2010-01-02 00:00:01.639000   null
2011-01-02 00:00:03.107000   null
2012-01-02 00:00:03.210000   null
2013-01-02 00:00:03.261000   null
2014-01-02 00:00:03.363000   null
2015-01-02 00:00:03.465000   null
2016-01-02 00:00:03.591000   null
2017-01-02 00:00:04.475000   null
2018-01-02 00:00:04.526000   null
2019-01-02 00:00:04.629000   null
2020-01-02 00:00:04.731000   null
```

Thank you!

Comment: Update for Postgresql: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea. You can always extract the year on Select. What happens when the date gets updated but the year column does not. If you **must** store it and use Postgres 12 (or later)  consider creating as a generated column. So

```
alter table add column year integer generated always as (extract (year from tdate)) stored;
```

This avoids the issue above update issue.  
Caution: Year is not really a good column name. While not a Postgres [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) it is a SQL standard reserved word. This *could* lead to unexpected errors in the future.

Comment: Thnank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Just `UPDATE` the table using `EXTRACT (YEAR from tdate)`:

```sql
UPDATE test_tb SET year = EXTRACT (YEAR from tdate);
```